# Allowing user create a category table advisable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I’m developing an inventory system with laravel,users can create categories and get a form dynamically to populate those categories,but I’m having an issue with querying the result into a responsive table cause of the data structure, I have the id, the category id and then the data in categorie_data table, when querying the result I find it difficult using table to make each data for each category stay under there category, it breaks if the user decides to create a new category apart from the old ones created,

so I’m thinking of making the  user create a table directly when creating a inventory/category and populate it his giving data’s that way  it would be easy for me to query, my question is, is it advisable to slow user create a table in the database and is there a better approach that would not involve creating a new table and I would be able to fomat the query result into a table

----------------------------------------------The table---------------------------------------

```
 <table class="table table-striped" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    @foreach  ($categoryDataname as $index => $category)
                        <th scope="col">{{ $category->category_name }}</th>
                        
                       
                        
                        @endforeach
                    <th scope="col">Total</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Populate this table with data from your database -->
                
                    <tr >
                            <td>
                               1
                                </td> 
                            
                            @foreach  ($categoryDataname as $category)

                           
                            
                        <td ><div class="div table-responsive color:red">
                           
                                  @foreach($categoryData->where('category_id',$category->id) as $data)
                                     {{ $data->data }}<br/><hr class="position:static"></hr>
                                  @endforeach
                                  
                             </div>
                        </td>
                        @endforeach
                        <td>
                            <!-- Calculate Total -->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               
                <!-- Add more rows for additional products -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

---------------------the inventory controller -----------------

```
class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
{
    $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
    $categoryData = DB::table('categories')
    ->where('user_email', '=', $userEmail)
    ->get(); 
    
    //return view('inventory.inventory', ['categoryData' => $categoryData]); it value has been returned in below

    $userEmail = auth()->user()->email; // Get the authenticated user's email

    $categoryData2 = CategoryData::whereHas('category', function($query) use ($userEmail) {
        $query->where('user_email', '=', $userEmail);
    })->get();
   


   return view('inventory.inventory', [
    'categoryData' => $categoryData2,
    'categoryDataname' => $categoryData,
   
]);
}

}
```

----------------categorydata model--------------------

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CategoryData extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories_data';
    protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'data']; // List of fillable attributes

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

-------------------category model--------------------

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
        'user_email',
        // Add any other fields that can be mass assigned here
    ];
public function categoryData()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryData::class, 'category_id');
}
}
```

Comment: why not eager load the category_data for each category, you already have the relation?

Comment: You should never let a application user create a database table.

Comment: How do I eager load the data ?